# Overwriting the createWindow function in PyQt

Tags: qt, webkit, pyqt

I'm trying to handle the `createWindow` method in PyQt webkit.  When you do this, PyQt gives the method a `QWebPage.WebWindowType` (or `QWebPage::WebWindowType` in c++).  All I need is a URL to create a new window, so I'm not sure what to do with this class.  The docs don't explain it very well either: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebpage.html#WebWindowType-enum

I'm trying to intergrate this with my "Tab" class:

```
class Tab(QtGui.QWidget):
    """
    Contains the variables and methods needed to open the Qt
    based user interface and the event bus to allow interaction.
    """
    def __init__(self, url, window):
        """
        Set the up the following:
          1) Initialise the Qt user interface.
          2) Set margins.
          3) Initialise the cookie jar.
          4) Set the default URL.
          5) Set the history buttons to disabled (there is not history yet).
          5) Hide the tools menu.
          6) Create the GUI event bus.
          7) Set keyboard bindings.
        """
        self.window = window
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Browser()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        l = self.layout()
        l.setMargin(0)
        self.ui.horizontalLayout.setMargin(0)

        try:
            self.ui.webView.page().networkAccessManager().setCookieJar(self.window.cookies)
        except:
            pass

        self.ui.webView.setUrl(url)
        self.ui.url.setText(url.toString())

        self.ui.back.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.forward.setEnabled(False)

        self.ui.toolsBox.hide()
        self.ui.tools.setChecked(False)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.back, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.back)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.forward, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.forward)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.refresh, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.refresh)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.url, QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.url)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.webView, QtCore.SIGNAL("linkClicked (const QUrl&)"), self.navigate)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.webView, QtCore.SIGNAL("urlChanged (const QUrl&)"), self.navigate)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.webView, QtCore.SIGNAL("titleChanged(const QString&)"), self.title)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.webView, QtCore.SIGNAL("loadStarted()"), self.showProgressBar)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.webView, QtCore.SIGNAL("loadProgress(int)"), self.setProgressBar)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.webView, QtCore.SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), self.hideProgressBar)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.toolPrint, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.printPage)
        self.ui.webView.createWindow = self.createWindow

        QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Backspace"), self, self.back)
        QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("F5"), self, self.refresh)
        QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+p"), self, self.printPage)

    def url(self):
        """
        Go to URL entered.
        """
        self.setHistory()
        url = self.ui.url.text()
        if not str(url).startswith("http://"):
            url = "http://" + url
        self.ui.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(url))

    def navigate(self, url):
        """
        Navigate to page requested.
        """
        self.setHistory()
        self.ui.url.setText(url.toString())

    def refresh(self):
        """
        Refresh the page.
        """
        self.ui.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(self.ui.webView.url()))

    def back(self):
        """
        Enable the back button.
        """
        page = self.ui.webView.page()
        history = page.history()
        history.back()
        if history.canGoBack():
            self.ui.back.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.ui.back.setEnabled(False)

    def forward(self):
        """
        Enable the forward button.
        """
        page = self.ui.webView.page()
        history = page.history()
        history.forward()
        if history.canGoForward():
            self.ui.forward.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.ui.forward.setEnabled(False)

    def title(self, title):
        """
        Change the title of the window.
        """
        self.window.tabs.setTabText(self.window.tabs.indexOf(self), title) or (self.window.setWindowTitle(title) if self.isThisFocused() else "New Tab")

    def createWindow(self, WebWindowType):
        """
        Overide the default behaviour.
        """
        tab = Tab(QtCore.QUrl("about:blank"), self.window)
        print(mode)
        if mode == QtWebKit.QWebPage.WebModalDialog:
            tab.ui.webView.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.window.tabs.setCurrentIndex(self.window.tabs.addTab(tab, ""))

    def isThisFocused(self):
        """
        Return whether this tab is focused or not.
        """
        if self.window.tabs.currentWidget() == self:
            return True
        return False

    def setHistory(self):
        """
        Check history and update buttons.
        """
        page = self.ui.webView.page()
        history = page.history()
        if history.canGoBack():
            self.ui.back.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.ui.back.setEnabled(False)
        if history.canGoForward():
            self.ui.forward.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.ui.forward.setEnabled(False)

    def showProgressBar(self):
        """
        We're loading a page, show the load progress bar.
        """
        self.ui.progress.show()

    def setProgressBar(self, percent):
        """
        Set the percentage of the progress bar.
        """
        self.ui.progress.setValue(percent)

    def hideProgressBar(self, bool):
        """
        We've finished loading the page, there is no need for the progress bar.
        """
        self.ui.progress.hide()

    def printPage(self):
        """
        Use Qt's goodness to print the page.
        """
        previewer = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog(paintRequested=self.ui.webView.print_)
        previewer.exec_()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'overwriting'? Do you mean hook the function?

Comment: Yes, by default, nothing happens and I'd like to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The [createWindow](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebview.html#createWindow) function is used for handling requests to open a new window (e.g. a javascript `window.open()` call).

By default, `createWindow` does nothing, so it must be reimplemented it in a subclass.

Also, to work with javascript, it is necessary that the [web-settings](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebview.html#settings) specify that javascript programs are [allowed to open new windows](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum).

Here's a demo script that illustrates how to use `createWindow`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit

class Browser(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    _windows = set()

    @classmethod
    def _removeWindow(cls, window):
        if window in cls._windows:
            cls._windows.remove(window)

    @classmethod
    def newWindow(cls):
        window = cls()
        cls._windows.add(window)
        return window

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWebKit.QWebView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.settings().setAttribute(
            QtWebKit.QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
        self.settings().setAttribute(
            QtWebKit.QWebSettings.JavascriptCanOpenWindows, True)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._removeWindow(self)
        event.accept()

    def createWindow(self, mode):
        window = self.newWindow()
        if mode == QtWebKit.QWebPage.WebModalDialog:
            window.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        window.show()
        return window

html = """
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var url = 'https://www.google.com'
var count = 0
function newWindow() {
    count += 1;
    window.open(url, 'testwindow' + count, 'width=640,height=480');
}
--></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="New Window" onclick="newWindow()" />
<p><a href="https://www.google.com">Test Link</a></p>
</body>
</html>"""

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = Browser()
    browser.setHtml(html)
    browser.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

(**NB**: It is essential that a reference is kept to any newly created windows; failure to do so will almost certainly result in segmentation faults).

**EDIT**:

Just to clarify:

The `createWindow` function is intended to handle *external* requests to open a new *browser* window (e.g. a javascript `window.open()` call, as in the example above). And note that `createWindow` is a *virtual* function. This means that if it is overridden in a subclass of `QWebView` or `QWebPage`, the reimplemented function can be called *internally* by Qt. This is obviously vital if you need your own `creatWindow` function to be called from javascript code.

So if you want javascript programs on web-pages to be able to create and open an instance of your browser window class, then *subclass* `QWebView` and reimplement its `createWindow` function (as in the example above).

The `createWindow` function is not required at all for simply creating and showing a `QWebView` (e.g. adding a new tab). A `QWebView` is just a container for displaying web-pages, and is created and shown just like any other widget.

Comment: Hi, please see the code I've added above.  How would I integrate it with that?  Ui_browser is an export from Qt.

Comment: @jdborg. Looking at the code you've posted, it seems you may have misunderstood the purpose of `createWindow`, so I've updated my answer with some further clarification.

Comment: It's not just javascript requests though.  If you right click and select "Open in new window", nothing happens either.  I'll try subclassing the QWebView.

Comment: By external request, I mean: not directly from your own program. I've added a link to my demo script to test the "Open in new window" command. For me, it works fine. There isn't enough relevant code in your example to say why it doesn't work. Try to create a small, self-contained example that clearly demonstrates your problem.

Comment: For example, if I wanted to integrate it with http://code.google.com/p/devicenzo/source/browse/trunk/devicenzo.py?spec=svn52&r=52

Comment: @jdborg. The code you linked to works in pretty much the same way that my example script does. If I comment out the `setCookieJar` line in `Tab.__init__`, it works fine for me. (NB: The runtime error is an entirely unrelated issue).

Comment: Could you show me how with some code please?  I'm still struggling, thanks.

Comment: @jdborg. I'm baffled... My answer already gives you a simple, working example, and the code you linked to is a complete, tabbed browser in only 128 lines of code! What more could you want?!